# How performance of reads/writes to regular file varies when linux kernel memory load becomes high?

Tags: linux, io, filesystems, kernel

It seems that writes/reads to regular files can't not be made non-blocking. I found the following references for support:

from The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook:

> "--- Nonblocking mode can be used with devices (e.g., terminals and pseudoterminals), pipes, FIFOs, and sockets. (Because file descriptors for pipes and sockets are not obtained using open(), we must enable this flag using the fcntl() F_SETFL operation described in Section 5.3.) O_NONBLOCK is generally ignored for regular files, because the kernel buffer cache ensures that I/O on regular files does not block, as described in Section 13.1. However, O_NONBLOCK does have an effect for regular files when mandatory file locking is employed (Section 55.4). ---"

from Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment 2nd Ed:

> "--- We also said that system calls related to disk I/O are not considered slow, even though the read or write of a disk file can block the caller temporarily. ---"

from http://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml:

> "--- Regular files are always readable and they are also always writeable. This is clearly stated in the relevant POSIX specifications. I cannot stress this enough. Putting a regular file in non-blocking has ABSOLUTELY no effects other than changing one bit in the file flags. Reading from a regular file might take a long time. For instance, if it is located on a busy disk, the I/O scheduler might take so much time that the user will notice the application is frozen. Nevertheless, non-blocking mode will not work. It simply will not work. Checking a file for readability or writeability always succeeds immediately. If the system needs time to perform the I/O operation, it will put the task in non-interruptible sleep from the read or write system call. ---"

When memory is adequately available, reads/writes is performed through kernel buffering.

My question is: is there a scenario that the kernel is out of memory that buffering is not usable immediately? If yes, what will kernel do? Simply returns an error or do some amazing trick?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Amazing trick: "Kernel panic"

Comment: According to the text you quoted, if there isn't memory for a buffer, it will lock the caller-provided buffer and sit and wait for the operation to complete before returning to the caller.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is what kernel does. Could anyone explain it more specifically from a kernel's viewpoint?

Answer (score 0):

My take on O_NONBLOCK and on quoted text:

- **O_NONBLOCK has absolutely no effect if a syscall which triggers an actual disk I/O blocks or not waiting for the I/O to complete**. O_NONBLCOK only affects filesystem level operations such as accesses to pseudo-files (as the first quote mentions) and to locked files. O_NONBLOCK does not affect any operations at the block device level.
- **Lack of memory has nothing to do with O_NONBLOCK.**
- O_NONBLOCK dictates if accesses to locked files block or not. For example, flock() / lockf() can be used to lock a file. If O_NONBLOCK is used, a read()/write() would return immediately with EGAIN instead of blocking and waiting for the file lock to be released. Please keep in mind that this synchronization differences are implemented at the level of the filesystem level and have nothing to do with whether the read()/write() syscall triggers a true disk I/O.
- The fragment `because the kernel buffer cache ensures that I/O on regular files does not block` from the first quote is misleading and I would go as far as considering it wrong. It is true that buffering lowers the chance for a file read/write syscall to result in a disk I/O and thus block, however, buffering alone can never fully avoid I/Os. If a file is not cached, the kernel needs to perform an actual IO when you read() from the file. If you write() to the file and the page cache is full with dirty pages, the kernel has to make room by first flushing some data to the storage device. *I feel that if you mentally skip this fragment the text becomes more clear.*
- The second quote seems generic (what does it mean for something to be slow?) and provides no explanation of why I/O-related calls are not considered slow. I suspect there is more background information in the text around it that qualifies a bit more what the author intended to say.
- Lack of memory in the kernel can come in two forms: (a) lack of free pages in the buffer cache and (b) not enough memory to allocate new data structures for servicing new syscalls. For (a) the kernel simply recycles pages in the buffer cache, possibly by writing dirty pages first to disk. This is a very common scenario. For (b) the kernel needs to free up memory either by paging program data to the swap partition or (if this fails) even by killing an existing process (the OOM function is invoked which pretty much kills the process with the biggest memory consumption). This is an uncommon mode of operation but the system will continue running after the user process is killed.